# django admin - count characters and show remaining space in text fields which are limited

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have some models which have `TextField()` with limitation like "only 85 available" and I want to write a js code which counts the remaining free space and shows the user.

but in admin templates, i see only some templates and i dont know which template i should put the code in. and also, i only want to count remaining space on limited fields and not on all fields of model.

i have tried with template  `admin > edit_line > stacked.html`, but nothing shows up in admin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I created a [form field widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/) to achieve this: https://github.com/timmyomahony/django-charsleft-widget)

You don't override admin templates, instead you create a widget (based on the default `TextInput` widget) that adds some extra JS to show the remaining characters:

```
class CharsLeftInput(forms.TextInput):                             
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        if value is None:
            value = ''
        final_attrs = self.build_attrs(attrs, type=self.input_type, name=name)
        if value != '':
            final_attrs['value'] = force_unicode(self._format_value(value))
        maxlength = final_attrs.get('maxlength',False)
        if not maxlength:
            return mark_safe(u'<input%s />'%flatatt(final_attrs))
        current = force_unicode(int(maxlength) - len(value))
        html = u"""
            <span class="charsleft charsleft-input">
            <input %(attrs)s /> 
            <span><span class="count">%(current)s</span> characters remaining</span>
            <span class="maxlength">%(maxlength)s</span>
            </span>
        """ % { 
            'attrs':flatatt(final_attrs),
            'current':current,
            'maxlength':int(maxlength),
        }
        return mark_safe(html)

    class Media:
        css = {'screen':('charsleft-widget/css/charsleft.css',),}
        js = ('charsleft-widget/js/charsleft.js',)
```

and the javascript:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $.fn.charsLeft = function(options){
        var defaults = {        
            'source':'input',
            'dest':'.count',
        }
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        var calculate = function(source, dest, maxlength){
            var remaining = maxlength - source.val().length;
            dest.html(remaining);
            /* Over 50%, change colour to orange */
            p=(100*remaining)/maxlength;
            if(p<25){
                dest.addClass('orange');
            }else if(p<50){
                dest.addClass('red');
            }else{
                dest.removeClass('orange red');
            }
        };

        this.each(function(i, el) {
            var maxlength = $(this).find('.maxlength').html();
            var dest = $(this).find(options.dest);
            var source = $(this).find(options.source);
            source.keyup(function(){
                calculate(source, dest, maxlength)
            });
            source.change(function(){
                calculate(source, dest, maxlength)
            });
        });
    };

    $(".charsleft-input").charsLeft({
            'source':'input',
            'dest':".count",
    });
});
```

and you can use the widget on particular `CharField` fields in your admin model:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from widgets import CharsLeftInput

class TestForm(forms.Form):
    field_one = forms.CharField(widget=CharsLeftInput())
    ....

class TestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = TestForm
```

you will probably need to play around with it to get exactly what you want, but you can see the code in the repo along with some more examples

Comment: awesome, i dont have form, i just have model fields as textfields, can i also attach your widget to this field like this ``field_one = models.CharField(widget=CharsLeftInput())``?

Comment: Is this supposed to update automatically when the text inside the Charfield is changed?

In my project it is not dynamic and will only update when the text is changed and the model saved, and the page reloaded. I am wondering whether I have a problem with the JS or this is intended.

Comment: As far as I remember it should change as the user types. It's quite an old snippet so I'm not sure if it will still work ok.

Comment: I just used it with a bit of changes, and it works like charm. I request a edit for those changes, so after approval it will work fine.